# avx512 register concatenation?

Tags: c, avx512

I am trying to efficiently gather 16 32-bit values from different locations in memory into a mm512i vector for further 32 bits SIMD operation:

Let's assume I have 16 buffers of 32 bits data whose 16 pointers are in an array c:

```
uint32_t buffer0[100];
uint32_t buffer1[100];
...
uint32_t buffer15[100];
uint32_t* c = [buffer0, buffer1, ... buffer15];
```

I want to initialise the _m512i vector with the contents (first word to start with) of these 16 arrays and to have a efficient way to move around my buffer data which I want to proces using 16*32 bit SIMD operation.
I have, so far, written the following to start with:

```
uint64_t base = c[0];
__m512i vindex0 = _mm512_setr_epi64 ((uint64_t)c[0],
                                     (uint64_t)c[1],
                                     (uint64_t)c[2],
                                     (uint64_t)c[3],
                                     (uint64_t)c[4],
                                     (uint64_t)c[5],
                                     (uint64_t)c[6],
                                     (uint64_t)c[7])
//create a list of offset from buffer0, hopefully fitting on 32 bits:
vindex0 = _mm512_sub_epi64(vindex0,_mm512_set1_epi64(base));

__m512i vindex1 = _mm512_setr_epi64 ((uint64_t)c[8],
                                     (uint64_t)c[9],
                                     (uint64_t)c[10],
                                     (uint64_t)c[11],
                                     (uint64_t)c[12],
                                     (uint64_t)c[13],
                                     (uint64_t)c[14],
                                     (uint64_t)c[15]);
//create a list of offset from buffer0, hopefully fitting on 32 bits
vindex1 = _mm512_sub_epi64(vindex1,_mm512_set1_epi64(base)); 

//now concatenate the 2 256 vectors of 8 32 address each into a 512b vector:
__m512i vindex = __MM512_CONCAT(_mm512_cvtsepi64_epi32(vindex0), 
                                _mm512_cvtsepi64_epi32(vindex1));
```

My main question is of course about finding the correct builtin to perform the concatenation above (the one I called __MM512_CONCAT).
But more generally I am wondering if this is the right approach. This requires all my buffers to be in a 4GB address space (or a multiple of 4GB
 if using the `_mm512_i32gather_epi32()` scale parameter and accepting buffer alignement requirement).

To further move around my data, I was planning to do something like:

```
__m512i increment = _mm512_set1_epi32 ((uint32_t)sizeof(uint32_t));
vindex = _mm512_add_epi32(vindex, increment);
//next 32b-word in each buffer:
data = _mm512_i32gather_epi32(vindex, base, 0);
```

If this is not the correct way to initialise 16x32 (=512) bits vector from scattered address space, them how should this be done??
If it is, what is the proper way to concatenate the 256b vectors, and how could a elegant saturation check be done when converting my 64 bits offset to 32 bits in `_mm512_cvtsepi64_epi32()` or at increment time?

Comment: So the main problem is that you're trying to gather 16 x 32-bit elements. But you can't because the pointers are all 64-bit? This may not be possible in your case, but if the source data can be compressed into a 32-bit integer offset. (if it's a table lookup or some sort)

Comment: Otherwise, there is `_mm512_i64gather_epi32()` which lets you gather 8 x 32-bit words using 8 x 64-bit offset. Do it twice and then `_mm512_inserti64x4()` to combine the two 256-bit results into 512-bit.

Comment: Yes, That should work. I guess I can cope with that so far. Not sure if it is intended to be used so, but might do the job...Thx

Comment: I guess you want to process all 100 elements of each buffer somehow. If you have enough registers (you've got 32 in avx512) just load 16 times 16 elements from each buffer with a simple load and then do a matrix transpose e.g. using permutex2var_epi32(). 16 Gathers take 9 * 16 = 144 cycles without combining anything, matrix transpose could be done in a maximum of 80 vpermi2d + 16 loads = 88 cycles.

Comment: Use `_mm512_loadu_si512` to load from your contiguous arrays like a normal person, not `_mm512_setr_epi64` with contiguous elements.